# Magento Magmi column mapper

Tags: product, magmi

I am using Magmi to import products in Magento DB. I am trying to map columns but I don't have  to map all columns because they have got right name. But only few columns needs to map but I couldn't figure it out, how can I do this.

Should I map all columns available in csv into the mapper ?

What the format mapped column we should put in to the column mapper? Say I have sku_name,category_name,product_type. How this s should be mapped ?

sku_name:sku,category_name:categories,product_type:type.

Is this right format?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

The way it works is actually pretty straight forward.  After clicking the configure link and getting the box, you first enter in the name of the column or columns that are in your CSV file in a comma separated format to the mapped columns list text box.  Then after clicking away from the text field, a new text field for each of the values you just entered will appear and you just fill in the name of the column you want the original to map too

So to use your example, you've got the columns sku_name, category_name, and product_type and you want those mapped to sku, category, and type, respectively.  So in the mapped columns list text field, enter in sku_name,category_name,product_type.  Then after clicking the mouse out of the text field, three new text fields will appear, one for each of the three column values you just entered.  From there, just fill out the rest of the form with the corresponding values, which in our case is sku, category, and type, and you're good to go.

The same kind of thing can apply to the configuration of other plugins too.  That's actually how I found out how column mapper works.  I was reading the wiki page for the default value setter plugin (http://sourceforge.net/apps/mediawiki/magmi/index.php?title=Default_Values_setter) and it mentioned clicking away causes new text fields to appear and it made me wonder if the same kind of principle would apply to other plugins.

Answer (score 0):

I have this as columns:

```
_store,_attribute_set,_type,_category,_root_category,_product_websites
```

I've just enter them in the "Mapped column list" input and on focus out a JavaScript builds under this input dinamic generated inputs like:

```
New name for col _store

New name for col _attribute_set

New name for col _type

New name for col _category

New name for col _root_category

New name for col _product_websites
```

In case you don't have this behaviour make sure you have JavaScript turned on and no other JavaScript error break this script.

Have fun!